# Is it possible to the use of one's own ActionLink Extension method rather than Razor's without signature change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC3, C#, ASP.NET4.5

I have created some ActionLink extension methods, mainly to implement URL hashing.

I have many ActionLinks around my application, and wondered whether it was possible to force the use of my own extension methods without altering the signature of the ActionLink in the many Views?

I have 2 approaches at present:

```
1) Specific Name ie ActionLinkHashed(

2) Unique signature ActionLink(true, "myLink","myAction","myController"...)
```

Both 1) and 2) could be implement by a global replace espcially 1). However I am sure there must be a better method.

Thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot overload any method on any class with another function with an identical signature. Otherwise, it would be ambiguous to the compiler which one was intended.

You will have to use a function with a different signature.  It would be best to do that by using your own name, to avoid potential future collisions with the framework.

Comment: Really appreciation the clarification. So you recommend 2) instead of 1) ?

Comment: I recommend 1) actually, though 2) will probably come with it naturally anyway.